# Time Complexity of a Recursive Algorithm with a Condition not Based on Size

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I have a question about the complexity of a recursive function
The code (in C#) is like this:

```
public void function sort(int[] a, int n)
{
    bool done = true;
    int j = 0;

    while (j <= n - 2)
    {
        if (a[j] > a[j + 1])
        {
            // swap a[j] and a[j + 1]
            done = false;
        {
        j++;
    }

    j = n - 1;

    while (j >= 1)
    {
        if (a[j] < a[j - 1])
        {
            // swap a[j] and a[j - 1]
            done = false;
        {
        j--;
    }

    if (!done)
        sort(array, length);
}
```

Now, the difficulty I have is the recursive part of the function.
In all of the recursions I have seen so far, we can determine the number of recursive calls based on the input size because every time we call the function with a smaller input etc.
But for this problem, the recursive part doesn't depend on the input size; instead it's based on whether the elements are sorted or not. I mean, if the array is already sorted, the function will run in O(n) because of the two loops and no recursive calls (I hope I'm right about this part).
How can we determine O(n) for the recursive part?

Answer (score 0):

O(f(n)) means that your algorithm is always faster or equal as f(n) regardless of input (considering only size of input). So you should find worst case for your input of size n.

This one looks like some bubble sort algorithm (although weirdly complicated) which is O(n^2). In worst case, every call of sort function takes O(n) and you transport highest number to the end of array - you have n items so its O(n)*O(n) => O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

This is bubble sort.  It's O(n^2).  Since the algorithm swaps adjacent elements, the running time is proportional to the number of inversions in a list, which is O(n^2).  The number of recursions will be O(n).  The backward pass just causes it to recurse about half the time but doesn't affect the actual complexity--it's still doing the same amount of work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,But my problem is that I can't get my head around the recursion part... You know, in a normal bubble sort, you iterate through the whole array and move the element, until the array is sorted (ie: total number of iterations is known), but here, we're only relying on the boolean "done" value. I suppose you're saying that the two passes causes the recursive part to be called n/2 times, but how can I somehow "prove" that?